# Apache htaccess 301 Redirect to subfolder causes too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

**Goal**

On an Apache httpd server, I would like to redirect requests made to `/cms/de/foo` to `/cms/de/foo/bar` permanently.

**Failed attempt**

Trying the following redirect in the `.htaccess`

```
Redirect 301 /cms/de/foo /cms/de/foo/bar
```

results in too many redirects.

- Request: http://threeohone.localhost/cms/de/foo
- Redirect: http://threeohone.localhost/cms/de/foo/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar/bar

As far as I understand it, the redirect is applied over and over again until it results in said error. An exact match could solve it, I believe, but I am unsure on how to accomplish it.

**Language part**

`de` represents the language and can be any of `de`, `en` and `fr`. Would it make sense to cover all languages within the same redirect or have explicit redirects for each language? The `foo` respectivley `foo/bar` path is the same for all languages.

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches on path _prefixes_. You need to either use `RedirectMatch` with a regex pattern that demands an _exact_ match, or mod_rewrite with a RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @CBRoe for pointing out `RedirectMatch`. This works:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/cms/de/foo$ /cms/de/foo/bar
```